# No module named 'fuzzywuzzy

Tags: python, postgresql, dbeaver

I have created function fuzzy_match in postgres database. I have also installed fuzzywuzzy on my machine using `pip3 install fuzzywuzzy` command and I can see fuzzywuzzy installed in my `python3.10\site_packages\` folder and I also see that I am using python version 3.10 when I run command `python3 --version`.

However when I run the below query in dbeaver enterprise I get a `No module named 'fuzzywuzzy'` error.

What could be the issue?

running

```
SELECT * FROM pg_extension WHERE extname = 'plpython3u';
```

sql shows plpython3u is installed and configured in postgres.

**Update 1:**

running following command shows `plpython3u version 1` is installed.

```
SELECT * FROM pg_available_extensions WHERE name LIKE 'plpython3u%';
```

**function creation:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION fuzzy_match(text, text, int) RETURNS boolean AS $$
   import fuzzywuzzy.process
   return fuzzy_match(text1, text2, threshold) 
$$ LANGUAGE plpython3u;
```

**sql command:**

```
SELECT t1.name, t2.name
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
WHERE fuzzy_match(t1.name, t2.name, 85);
```

Comment: Postgres might be using something different than what you have as your default version. Can respond with the output of `SELECT plpython3u_version();`.

Also, just to beat a dead horse even more, perhaps try `python3.10 -m pip install fuzzywuzzy`.

Comment: plpython3u_version() returns function plpython3u_version does not exist. but i see that plpython3u version 1 installed. I ran `python3.10 -m pip install fuzzywuzzy` and it told that fuzzywuzzy is already installed on my Ubuntu machine. Is Dbeaver configured with a different python than what I have default on my machine?

Comment: Thank you @BenA., I was able to get it working using difflib library instead of fuzzywuzzy.

Comment: 1) DBeaver uses JDBC(Java). 2) Is the Postgres server located on same machine as where you installed `fuzzywuzzy`? 3) Was `fuzzywuzzy` installed in a virtualenv?